# Is there a C/C++ cryptography API available in Windows Phone 8 with AES-256 support?

Tags: cryptography, windows-phone-8, aes, windows-phone

It appears that the Windows CryptoAPI is available for desktop apps only. Is there any system-level C or C++ crypto API I can use to perform AES-256 encryption in Windows Phone 8 or do I have to call into .NET and use AesManaged?

I've tried to look for documentation on this in MSDN but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why do you need CryptoAPI just for AES? There is a number of C/C++ open source libraries with AES implementation.

Comment: Code size and maintainability, export laws, FIPS compliance.

Comment: Code size for AES algorithm is around 100-200 lines of code (not counting pre-calculated tables). Export laws, FIPS compliance - that could be the reason, agree.

Comment: Try Microsoft CNG (Cryptography Next Generation)

Comment: Have you tried using the same API as for AES-128 but with a 32 byte key?

Comment: @PavelOgnev The documentation for both CryptoAPI and CNG functions say "desktop apps only", yet http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/KBKDF800-108/kbkdfval.htm seems to imply that CNG is available on Windows Phone 8. I guess the best way to see if these functions are available in WinRT is to simply go try and compile an app.

Comment: https://github.com/panahiehsancom/AESWinAPI

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged. It's there for Windows Phone and has a 256 bit KeySize.  The example code is on MSDN too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

To show that it is AES-256, copy the example code into your Windows Phone project's MainPage.cs file.  Be sure to be using System, System.IO, and System.Security.Cryptography.  Call the Main function from the page's constructor and set a breakpoint on the "byte[] encrypted = ..." line.  When that breakpoint is hit, inspect myAes.KeySize and you'll see that it is 256 bits.

Comment: I don't want to write C++/C# marshaling code if not absolutely necessary.